# SQLiteStatement why no method for SELECT statement - any workaround plus why no thread safe

Tags: java, android, sqlite

DO you know any workaround how to precompile SELECT statement returning Cursor and to use it multiple times (I'm 99% sure that it's possible with sqlite as java desktop driver allows precompilation with SELECT returning cursor)? Unfortunately as source I can't use QueryBuilder but pure SQL String type SELECT statement  (with ? for parameters). Precompilation would be great because of efficiency.

Plus what means in practice that SQLiteStatement is not thread safe? How could I replace it to be threads safe and efficient (precompilation)?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any way to precompile sqlite statement from sqlite command line? Perhaps that would be some direction... but unfortunately I'm not able to find any sqlite native command to precompile. :(

Comment: Rerutning to thread safe issue - If i have two different connections to the same database and I will use SQLiteStatement, is that safe or not (in multiple threads program)?

Comment: If you have 2 different `SQLiteStatement` instances, it should work without problems.

Answer (score 1):

To precompile a statement, use the [compileStatement function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29):

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("SELECT X FROM Y WHERE Z = ?");
...
stmt.bindString(1, "foo");
String x = stmt.simpleQueryForString();
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to return a cursor from such a precompiled statement.
If you want to get multiple rows or columns, you have to use `query` or `rawQuery`.

Please note that SQLite is quite fast; you should not bother optimizing statement compilation unless you have actually measured it to be a bottleneck in your app.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that for simple query but I need to use it for quite complicated statement which returns cursor. And here my problem starts.... no cursor returning function for precompiled statements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me that pre-compiling a SELECT with replaceable parameters (the ? placeholders) is any more efficient than issuing a query using SQLiteDatabase.query(). What is leading to believe that you need to compile the statement?

Comment: If you use the same SELECT only once, probably there is no difference or even playing with precompiled statements can take more. If you use similar select ex. 1000 times every 1 second with different parameters (?) it makes difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `rawQuery()` probably precompiles the statement internally.

The arguments have to be converted to String, in comparison to `SQLiteStatement` that support more data types.